# How can i access Model POJO class object in properties file?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties-file

I am tring to access model object variables in proerties file like below.
**Properties file:**

```
User.Name             = ${User.name}
```

Here User is model object which was returned from controller, having name variable.

**Jsp File:**

```
 <spring:message  code="User.Name"/>
```

**Output:**
  [image]

Please help me to resolve this issue or any suggestions.

Comment: That variable replacement is not happining

Comment: https://github.com/donhuvy/java_examples/blob/master/spring_mvc_multi_language/src/main/resources/messages_en_US.properties#L1 and  https://github.com/donhuvy/java_examples/blob/master/spring_mvc_multi_language/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/welcome.jsp#L11